# OpenGL visible area width and height

Tags: opengl

I can't figure out how to get the width and height of the currently visible area.

I might going all wrong about this so I'll just in case:
what I want to do is create a background image.
My problem is that I don't know the measures(coordinates) for the QUAD I need to create.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use any projections or transformations, the visible area is always from -1 to 1 on each axis. So if you draw a quad that has vertices at

```
[-1, -1, 0],
[1, -1, 0],
[1, 1, 0],
[-1, 1, 0],
```

then this will cover the whole visible area.

Comment: Thank you for your help! As I zoom in or out by modifying the Z is there a way to keep my quad covering the entire visible area?

Comment: As long as there is no projection, there will be no zooming effect. As long as you keep z between [-1,1] it will be visible and look the same.